# ORACLE EXCHANGE PARTITION and PARTITION INDEXES

Tags: oracle, indexing, partitioning

In order to compress the data in a single partition, I use the following approach:

```
-- I create a table with the same structure of the ORIGINAL TABLE, but
-- on a new tablespace (NEW_TBS_DATA)

CREATE TABLE AUXILIARY_TABLE TABLESPACE NEW_TBS_DATA AS 
SELECT * FROM ORIGINAL_TABLE WHERE 1=0

-- I create the index on the AUXILIARY_TABLE, on a new tablespace 
-- for indexes (NEW_TBS_IDX)

CREATE   INDEX I_1 ON AUXILIARY_TABLE( START_DATE) TABLESPACE NEW_TBS_IDX
CREATE   INDEX I_2 ON AUXILIARY_TABLE( ID_FILE) TABLESPACE NEW_TBS_IDX
CREATE   INDEX I_3 ON AUXILIARY_TABLE( DESCRIPTION) TABLESPACE NEW_TBS_IDX
CREATE   INDEX I_4 ON AUXILIARY_TABLE( ZIP_CODE) TABLESPACE NEW_TBS_IDX
CREATE   INDEX I_5 ON AUXILIARY_TABLE( BH_TRAFFIC) TABLESPACE NEW_TBS_IDX 

-- I move data from partition 20160529 to auxiliary_table

ALTER TABLE ORIGINAL_TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION PARTITION_20160529 WITH TABLE AUXILIARY_TABLE INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION

-- I compress data using the new tablespace NEW_TBS_DATA on auxiliary_table

ALTER TABLE AUXILIARY_TABLE  MOVE  TABLESPACE NEW_TBS_DATA PARALLEL 4 COMPRESS

-- I move the data back to the original table, with the same exchange statement:

ALTER TABLE ORIGINAL_TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION PARTITION_20160529 WITH TABLE AUXILIARY_TABLE including indexes without validation

-- I drop the auxiliary_table

DROP TABLE AUXILIARY_TABLE CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE
```

Why, at the end of the process, the partition INDEXES are on the old tablespace instead of the new tablespace (NEW_TBS_IDX)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section "including indexes" takes affect only for local indexes. See
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin002.htm
section(Exchanging Partitions)

Comment: What can I do in order to realize that after the second EXCHANGE PARTITION statement, the indexes are on NEW_TBS_IDX instead of on OLD_TBS_IDX?